# How to use pcg with a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, sparse-matrix, equation-solving, function-handle

I am going to solve an inverse problem, `AX=b`, using conjugate gradient method in MATLAB. I want to use `pcg` function in MATLAB and as I know instead of matrix `A` I can use a function.

I have a function for example `afun` which has some entries. In the documents, I have seen that the `afun` function is entered in `pcg` function without entries, however, when I do the same, the error `not enough input arguments` appears.  I use a code like this:

```
b = afun(ent1,ent2);
x = pcg(@afun,b,tol,max_iter);
```

How should I use my function in `pcg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the function handle should the have the signature `afun(x)` and return `A*x`.

Your function apparently takes two inputs... You need to use a anonymous function to wrap the call, something like this:

```
% I dont know what these ent1/ent2 represent exactly,
% so you must complete the ".." part first
fcn = @(x) afun(x, ..)

% now you can call PCG
x = pcg(fcn, b, tol, maxiter);
```

There is a doc page explaining how to [parameterize functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) to pass extra args using [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html).